# Parameter value did not match expected type (Spring Data JPA)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have class A and B

```
public class A{
@Id
String id;
private B b;
}

public class B{
@Id
String id;
private List<A> a;
}
```

I'm using `@Query`for my query since my query is too long for Query creation .

```
@Query("select a from A a where  b = :b")
public List<A> findSomething(@Param("b") String bId);
```

However, when I use that query it shows

```
Parameter value  did not match expected type [B (n/a)]
```

Comment: The B you have declared is an object and the b you are passing is an Id.

Comment: I tried using b.id so the query is changed to this
`@Query("select a from A a where  b.id = :b")
public List<A> findSomething(@Param("b") String bId);`
However it shows 
`operator does not exist: character varying = bytea`

Comment: Can you update the question with table structure as  may the foreign key is wrong. When using Hibernate, the foreign key should always point to the id (primary key) of the other table. if not so it will the problem u mentioned in comments

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a.b.id` instead of `b.id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change query to "select a from A a where  a.b.id = :b". It will work